# CakePHP 2.1.1. testAction() undefined

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm just trying out PHPUnit with CakePHP and i'm getting an the following error when trying to use the testAction() method in a controller test case.

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method GroupsControllerTestCase::testAction()**

The controller test case was baked with the console and i'm using the following from the 2.x docs.

```
public function testIndex() {
    $result = $this->testAction('/groups/index');
    debug($result);
}
```

**GroupsControllerTest.php**

```
<?php
App::uses('GroupsController', 'Controller');


class TestGroupsController extends GroupsController {

public $autoRender = false;

public function redirect($url, $status = null, $exit = true) {
    $this->redirectUrl = $url;
}
}


class GroupsControllerTestCase extends CakeTestCase {

public $fixtures = array('app.group');


public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
    $this->Groups = new TestGroupsController();
    $this->Groups->constructClasses();
}

public function tearDown() {
    unset($this->Groups);

    parent::tearDown();
}

public function testIndex() {
    $results = $this->testAction('/groups/index');
    debug($results);
}
.....
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more information? Like your PHP version and few lines at the beginning of your test file?

Comment: Sure, running PHP 5.3.6 (MAMP). I'll update my question with the test case file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your test case should extend ControllerTestCase, not CakeTestCase.

```
class GroupsControllerTestCase extends ControllerTestCase {
    ...
```